# Calculating congruence with high exponent

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

I am attempting to solve the following congruence: $420292^{257} \equiv x \pmod {481391}$ The main method that I know to simplify this power is to use powers of $2$ so $257^2 = 66049$, however this is less than the modulus and is congruent to itself, and the numbers keep increasing incredibly large that I feel this is not the correct method.

I have also been considering Euclid's algorithm, but the problem with the power still remains.

What other approach can I try to simplify this congruence?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: factor $481391$ and then use Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the solution I am looking for as I overlooked that previously I calculated this modulus using two relatively prime numbers, 641 and 751.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a = 420292$.
Repeated squaring will give you
$a^2\mod 481391, a^4 \mod 481391, a^8 \mod 481391, \ldots, a^{256} \mod 481391$.  Then $a^{257} = a \cdot a^{256}$.

But I hope you're not doing the computations by hand, so you might as well just [ask the computer for the whole thing](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=420292%5E257+mod+481391).

Comment: I can use a calculator but not a computer, also in a previous question I had found that 751*641 = 481391